# COM Object Arrays From VB

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, vba, com

I'm developing a COM Object in C#, Visual studio 2010, .NET 3.5, x86
which I'm using it in a VBA program.

```
namespace Test
{
    [Guid("8b65089f-5d98-41e7-9579-1ee384948e4c")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct Contact
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] 
        public string Test1;
        public string[] Array;
    }


    [Guid("8b65082f-5d98-41e7-9579-1ee384948e4e"), ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IInContainer
    {
        Contact[] Contacts { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT)] get; set; }
        string[] strings { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT)] get; set; }

    }

    [Guid("8b65089f-5d98-41e7-9579-1ee384948e4b"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual), ComVisible(true)]
    public class InContainer
    {
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public Contact[] Contacts { get;set;}
        public string[] strings { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I'm able to see the structure/interface of the object in VB when I create it.

I can change the information in Container.strings from VB without any issue.

However, I cannot change the information in the Contact array (with the Contact structs) via VB.

Lets say the Contact array i 1 long, that node have all values set to "test". When trying to change it via VB i.e. `Container.Contact(0).Test1 = "Monkey"` I get no error. When trying to read it directly after i.e. `Print(Container.Contact(0).Test1)` I get "", or whatever default string I set.

I'm able to change the information in a contact by using a method on the container object, this is undesirable however.

So I need help why the values are read only in Container.Contact array.

Comment: In your quest to avoid "undesirable", you've actually written code that uses, oh, about a dozen methods and still doesn't get the job done.  What was the point of this?  Have you actually *measured* the cost of the code?   Only real way to find out that your alternative is thousands of times slower, VBA gives no other good ways to find out what kind of code runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically editing a copy of the struct, which is directly discarded after your assignment (because it is not kept in a variable).

If you decompose what `Container.Contact(0).Test1 = "Monkey"` does you get the following:

- A copy of the `Contact` item at index 0 is created (because structs are value types)
- The property `Test1` is assigned the value "Monkey" *on the copy* of the contact
- The copy of the contact struct with the modified `Test1` property is discarded
- When calling `Print(Container.Contact(0).Test1)` the original Contact struct still in the array is copied again, and the `Test1` property of this newly created copy is printed.

One solution is to change your `Contact` type from struct to class<sup>1</sup>, or to replace the entire struct at the specified array index instead of trying to change just a single property or field.

```
dim cntct as Contact
cntct = Container.Contact(0)
cntct.Test1 = "Monkey"
Container.Contact(0) = cntct
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> Unless you are certainly sure that a struct is required here you probably want to change from struct to class.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I changed to a class created a interface for Contact but now i get syntax error:
"Wrong Number of parameters" @
`Container.Contacts(0).Test1 = "Monkey"`. The rest remains the same, thoughts?

Comment: Did you define `Test1` as a property with getter and setter, i.e. `public string Test1 { get; set; };`?

Comment: Yeah full conversion to Class with propertys and interface

Comment: I'll move this to a new question